# Copy data to member of structure using memcpy given a double pointer to the structure

Tags: c++, memcpy

I want to copy data to a struct member given a double pointer to that structure.
I cannot change the signature of `copyFoo()`.
The member cnt is assigned the return value of `GetCnt()` as expected, but `memcpy` creates access violations when I use it like this.
Could someone elaborate how memcpy is to be used when I have a double pointer to a struct and a void pointer member? Thank you very much!

```
struct mystruct
{
    void * data;
    unsigned int cnt;

};

void copyFoo( myObj * inBar, mystruct **outFoo)
{
  memcpy((*outFoo)->data, inBar->GetData(), inBar->GetLength() );
  (*outFoo)->cnt=  inBar->GetCnt();
}

int main(void){

myObj *in = getObj();
mystruct *out= new mystruct;
copyFoo(in, &out));
delete in;
delete out;

}
```

memberfunction `GetData()` of `inbar` returns a void pointer, `GetCnt()` returns `unsigned int` and `GetLength()` returns an `int`.

Comment: Can you also show the code which calls `copyFoo` please?

Comment: assuming `inBar` is a valid address, did you bother to set `inBar->data` to a sufficiently sized memory buffer allocation before invoking that memcpy? If not, you're invoking **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A memory block with appropriate size should be allocated before you try to copy the data into it:

```
void copyFoo(myObj *inBar, mystruct **outFoo)
{
    (*outFoo)->data = malloc(inBar->GetLength());                     // <-- THIS
    memcpy((*outFoo)->data, inBar->GetData(), inBar->GetLength());
    (*outFoo)->cnt=  inBar->GetCnt();
}
```

in case the `data` member of `mystruct` is not yet initialized or points to the memory, which  has already been freed, the `copyFoo` function invokes the ***undefined behavior***.